# Convert integer into its character equivalent, where 0 => a, 1 => b, etc

Tags: javascript, integer, alphabet

I want to convert an integer into its character equivalent based on the alphabet. For example:

```
0 => a
1 => b
2 => c
3 => d
```

etc. I could build an array and just look it up when I need it but I’m wondering if there’s a built in function to do this for me. All the examples I’ve found via Google are working with ASCII values and not a character’s position in the alphabet.

Comment: The lowercase letters are ordered alphabetically in ASCII.

Comment: Even the digits ;-)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Assuming you want lower case letters:

```
var chr = String.fromCharCode(97 + n); // where n is 0, 1, 2 ...
```

97 is the ASCII code for lower case 'a'. If you want uppercase letters, replace 97 with 65 (uppercase 'A'). Note that if `n > 25`, you will get out of the range of letters.

Answer (score 89):

Will be more portable in case of extending to other alphabets:

```
char='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[code]
```

or, to be more compatible (with our beloved IE):

```
char='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.charAt(code);
```

Comment: Much more elegant than `String.fromCharCode` in my opinion, as as you said, it extends very easily.

Comment: And when you have no need of extending, maybe more prone to errors?  abcede

Comment: And it will give `undefined` in case of bad code, which is more sensible that some weird white rectangles.

Comment: FYI JScript (IE) does not support the index operator `[]` on strings.

Comment: @Crescent, the `[]` property accessor on strings is supported on IE from IE8 up (IE8 in IE7 compat mode also doesn't works), [`String.prototype.chatAt`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.5.4.4) is preferred instead of `[]` for browser compatibility. E.g. `'foo'.charAt(0) == 'f'`

Comment: @Crescent, forgot to mention that the `[]` property accessor on strings is standardized on ECMAScript 5 (see [\[\[GetOwnProperty\]\](P)](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.5.5.2)).

Comment: @Crescent, @CMS, thanks for your comments, I have upgraded the answer to reflect them.

Comment: I agree with the char='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.charAt(code); version, this is IMO the cleanest way.

Comment: I love this approach, and if you want to add more characters, you can do so, without getting into the complication of finding the ASCII code. For example the char ñ '...mnñop...' for the Spanish alphabet.

Answer (score 35):

If you don't mind getting multi-character strings back, you can support arbitrary positive indices:

```
function idOf(i) {
  return (
    (i >= 26 ? idOf(((i / 26) >> 0) - 1) : "") +
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[i % 26 >> 0]
  );
}

[0, 1, 25, 26, 27, 701, 702, 703].map(idOf);
// ['a', 'b', 'z', 'aa', 'ab', 'zz', 'aaa', 'aab']
```

(Not thoroughly tested for precision errors :)

Comment: Recursive function, very nice!

Comment: @mikemaccana, why this edit? I think it makes it harder to read. Now I have to scroll horizontally to read the code.

Comment: @z0r So people using the code won't have to fix the newline. There's no reason to break lines arbitrarily, editors will wrap at the character size of their window.

Comment: Nice idea, but it didn't work until changed into this :```function idOf(i) {
  return (i >= 26 ? idOf(Math.floor(i / 26) -1 ) : '') + 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[i % 26]; 
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking or

Answer (score 20):

A simple answer would be (26 characters):

```
String.fromCharCode(97+n);
```

If space is precious you could do the following (20 characters):

```
(10+n).toString(36);
```

Think about what you could do with all those extra bytes!

How this works is you convert the number to base 36, so you have the following characters:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
^         ^
n        n+10
```

By offsetting by 10 the characters start at `a` instead of `0`.

Not entirely sure about how fast running the two different examples client-side would compare though.

Comment: I enjoyed your base 36 creativity

Answer (score 10):

I don't like all the solutions that use magic numbers like `97` or `36`.

```
const A = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);

let numberToCharacter = number => String.fromCharCode(A + number);

let characterToNumber = character => character.charCodeAt(0) - A;
```

this assumes uppercase letters and starts 'A' at 0.

Answer (score 6):

Javascript's String.fromCharCode(code1, code2, ..., codeN) takes an infinite number of arguments and returns a string of letters whose corresponding ASCII values are code1, code2, ... codeN. Since 97 is 'a' in ASCII, we can adjust for your indexing by adding 97 to your index.

```
function indexToChar(i) {
  return String.fromCharCode(i+97); //97 in ASCII is 'a', so i=0 returns 'a', 
                                    // i=1 returns 'b', etc
}
```

Comment: Well, to be pedantic, it takes a *variable* number of arguments, not an *infinite* number.

Answer (score 4):

There you go: (a-zA-Z)

```
function codeToChar( number ) {
  if ( number >= 0 && number <= 25 ) // a-z
    number = number + 97;
  else if ( number >= 26 && number <= 51 ) // A-Z
    number = number + (65-26);
  else
    return false; // range error
  return String.fromCharCode( number );
}
```

input: 0-51, or it will return false (range error);

OR:

```
var codeToChar = function() {
  var abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
  return function( code ) {
    return abc[code];
  };
})();
```

returns undefined in case of range error.
NOTE: the array will be created only once and because of closure it will be available for the the new codeToChar function. I guess it's even faster then the first method (it's just a lookup basically).

Comment: That works with ASCII, I need to work with the position of the character in the alphabet.

Comment: @VIVA - I think you could have worked this out?
@Galambalaza - I think you want 65 not 64

Comment: i just showed how simple it is. he could've worked this out. but there you go. see the update

Answer (score 4):

Use `String.fromCharCode`. This returns a string from a Unicode value, which matches the first 128 characters of ASCII.

```
var a = String.fromCharCode(97);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with @mikemaccana's great solution is that it uses the binary >> operator which is costly, performance-wise. I suggest this modification to his great work as a slight improvement that your colleagues can perhaps read more easily.

```
const getColumnName = (i) => {
     const previousLetters = (i >= 26 ? getColumnName(Math.floor(i / 26) -1 ) : '');
     const lastLetter = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[i % 26]; 
     return previousLetters + lastLetter;
}
```

Or as a one-liner

```
const getColumnName = i => (i >= 26 ? getColumnName(Math.floor(i / 26) -1 ) : '') + 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[i % 26];
```

Example:

```
getColumnName(0); // "A"
getColumnName(1); // "B"
getColumnName(25); // "Z"
getColumnName(26); // "AA"
getColumnName(27); // "AB"
getColumnName(80085) // "DNLF"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(n+10).toString(36)
```

```js
chr = n=>(n+10).toString(36);

for(i=0; i<26; i++) console.log(`${i} => ${ chr(i) }`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for TypeScript working functions then follow

```
public numericValue = (alphaChar: any) => alphaChar.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - 64;

public alphaValue = (numericDigit: any) => 
   String.fromCharCode(64 + numericDigit) : '';
```

You can make several checks like `(numericDigit >= 1 && numericDigit <= 26) ?`  inside function body as per the requirements.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you want uppercase case letters:

```
function numberToLetter(num){
        var alf={
            '0': 'A', '1': 'B', '2': 'C', '3': 'D', '4': 'E', '5': 'F', '6': 'G'
        };
        if(num.length== 1) return alf[num] || ' ';
        return num.split('').map(numberToLetter);
    }
```

Example:

**numberToLetter('023')** is **["A", "C", "D"]**

**numberToLetter('5')** is **"F"**

[image: number to letter function]