# Display help text with with <select> option

Tags: jquery, html

So I would like to have some text be displayed for each , say I had this:

```
<select id="321" name="123">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
<div id="help"></div>
```

How would I make the `a` option display "A is the first letter of the alphabet!" in the help div with jquery? And similar for the rest.

Comment: I don't believe jQuery knows the alphabet...

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com?

Comment: why don't you add id to your options ?

Comment: @F4r-20 [With a little work, it can](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9905533/901048)

Comment: One option I haven't seen in the answers is to create a `<div>` in `#help` for each `<option>`, and use jQuery to hide all but the selected one. This avoids the implicit limitations (e.g. can't use markup) caused by having the help text in an attribute.

Comment: @Blazemonger *With a little work* Anything is possible ;)

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I thought about doing that, but I knew there must be some way to get a string and display it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have to have the values of the text stored somewhere.  You could create a function that gets the English spelling of the numeric count and build it dynamically, but I don't think something like that exists already.  Anyway, if you're willing to type a little:

```
<select ...>
   <option data-description="A is the first letter of the alphabet!">a</option>
   ...


$("#321").on('change', function () {
   $("#help").text($(this).find(':selected').data('description'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a `data` attribute to store the text, unless you know of a plugin which has some kind of AI and knows it's alphabet and can return a string.

```
<select id="321" name="123">
    <option value="a" data-message="A is the first letter of the alphabet!">a</option>
    <option value="b" data-message="B is the second letter of the alphabet!">b</option>
    <option value="c" data-message="C is the third letter of the alphabet!">c</option>
    <option value="d" data-message="D is the fourth letter of the alphabet!">d</option>
</select>
<div id="help"></div>
```

```js
$('#321').change(function() {
    $('#help').text($('option:selected', this).data('message'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution for this issue :

```
<select id="321" name="123">
    <option id='a' value="a">a</option>
    <option id='b' value="b">b</option>
    <option id='c' value="c">c</option>
    <option id='d' value="d">d</option>
</select>
<div id="help"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var alghabet = new Array('first','second','third','fourth');
        $("option").hover(
        function() {
            var i = $(this).index();
            var value = $(this).attr("value").toUpperCase();
            $("#help").html(value + " is the " + alghabet[i] + " letter of the alphabet!");
        }
    );
    });
</script>
```