# jQuery calculate column count from excel range

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, excel

I have a C# web form where a user inputs data about an excel file into a number of text boxes, including:

- `TXT_FirstDataRow` - integer field which represents the first row that contains data
- `TXT_LastDataColumn` - string field which represents the last column that contains data
- `TXT_Range` - string field which contains the calculated data range using the above two fields
- `TXT_ColumnCount` - The number of columns in the calculated range

I am currently using jQuery to automatically calculate the data range using the code below which works perfectly:

```
$('#TXT_FirstDataRow,#TXT_LastDataColumn').keyup(function () {

    var row = $('#TXT_FirstDataRow').val();
    var column = $('#TXT_LastDataColumn').val();
    var range = 'A' + row + ':' + column; //All ranges start at column A

    $('#TXT_Range').val(range);
});
```

I would now like to automatically populate the `TXT_ColumnCount` with the count of the columns. For example:

```
Range |Column Count
------+------------
A1:C  |3
A7:BX |76
```

I imagine that this should be made easier as the **ranges will always be starting from column A**, so the column count should just be the equivalent column number of `TXT_LastDataColumn`, but I am afraid even this is beyond my slightly limited jQuery knowledge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you allowed to use excel interop?

Comment: @Rex Thanks for your reply, I was hoping to do something neat in jQuery/Javascript rather than using any libraries such as npoi or epplus. Also the the server that the web app will be running on does not have office installed so I guess interop is not an option either.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/range.md) example. It is in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on SO that helped me, link below:

[Convert excel column alphabet (e.g. AA) to number (e.g., 25)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905533/convert-excel-column-alphabet-e-g-aa-to-number-e-g-25)

```
function letterToNumbers(string) {
    string = string.toUpperCase();
    var letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', sum = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        sum += Math.pow(letters.length, i) * (letters.indexOf(string.substr(((i + 1) * -1), 1)) + 1);
    }
    return sum;
}
```