# Numeric text replace to alphabet using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have any in a list item like `0123` then it will show `abcd`. again if it `5462` then will show `fegc`. my html code is below:

```
<div class="myList">
 - 0123
 - 5462
 - 0542
</div>
Converted output will be
//////////
<div class="myList">
 - abcd
 - fegb
 - afec
</div>
```

Is it possible to create using javascript?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145030/convert-integer-into-its-character-equivalent-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, it is. Give it a try, and if you have a *specific* question along the way, post that question. Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is specific to your question.

```js
alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];
function toNewString(input){
  inputArray = input.split('');
  for(i=0;i<inputArray.length; i++){
      if(!isNaN(inputArray[i]))
      inputArray[i] = alpha[inputArray[i]];
  }   
  return inputArray.join('');
}
$('.myList').html(toNewString($('.myList').html()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myList">
 - 0123
 - 5462
 - 0542
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```js
var str = '0123';
var new_str = '';
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  new_str += String.fromCharCode(97 + parseInt(str[i]));
}
alert(new_str)
```

The following will take the text from the element and change it accordingly while skipping non integer characters

```js
$('.myList').text(convertNumbersToLetters($('.myList').text()))

function convertNumbersToLetters(numbers) {
  new_str = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    new_str += isInt(numbers[i]) ? String.fromCharCode(97 + parseInt(numbers[i])) : numbers[i];
  }
  return new_str;
}

function isInt(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseInt(n));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myList">- 0123 - 5462 - 0542</div>
```

Comment: Great @DGS !!! but, this is working with only one item ... but if i have a list and there is different number in every list item then how will i manage this ???

can you explain me please?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this (@DGS edited)

```
var str = ['0123', '456'];
var new_str = '';

for(var j=0; j < str.length; j++)
{
for (var i = 0; i < str[j].length; i++) {
  new_str += String.fromCharCode(97 + parseInt(str[j][i]));
}
alert(new_str);
new_str = '';
}
```