# Sum cells if they are not strikethrough

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm a little bit stuck with my Google Apps script purposed to calculate a sum of cells which are *not* <s>strikethrough</s>.

Here is its source:

```
function SumIfNotStrikethrough(rangeA1Notation)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var mysheet = sheet.getActiveSheet();

  var dataRange = mysheet.getDataRange();
  var mydatarange = mysheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var numRows = mydatarange.getLastRow();
  var rowindex = mydatarange.getRowIndex();
  var columnindex = mydatarange.getColumnIndex();

  var total =0;

  for(i=rowindex;i<=numRows;i++)
  {
    if(dataRange.offset(i-1, columnindex-1, 1, 1).isBlank() != true && dataRange.offset(i-1, columnindex-1, 1, 1).getFontLine() != "line-through")
    {
      var temp = dataRange.offset(i-1, columnindex-1, 1, 1).getValue();
      total = total + temp;
    }    
  }

  return total;
}
```

Here is its formula: `=SumIfNotStrikethrough("J2")`.

I have two questions here:

1. How to add the Google Apps script to use this formula as, for example, `SumIfNotStrikethrough(J2)` rather than `SumIfNotStrikethrough("J2")`?  Quotes are so annoying in terms of changing its range manually after scaling the formula on other cells :-(. What should be changed in the source code?
2. When I run this script I face with following error:

> Range not found (line 9, file "SumIfNotStrikethrough"

Thus, how can I fix it?

UPD № 1. Here is an example with a string reference, but it only counts the number of cells:

```
function countStrike(range) {
    var count = 0;
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
            .getRange(range)
            .getFontLines()
        .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a.concat(b);
        })
        .forEach(function (el) {
            if (el === "line-through") {
                count++
            }
        });
    return count;
}
```

UPD № 2. Unfortunately, this question is different from my previous question "Sum cells if they are not bold". I respectively tried to change the script, but it didn't work. Yes, it sums cells *but it sums all the cells with strike-through and without* :-(.

Here is what I changed:

```
function SumIfNotStrikethrough(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i)[1].split("!");
  try {
    if (args.length == 1) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(args[0]);
    }
    else {
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName(args[0].replace(/'/g, ''));
      range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args.join("!") + " is not a valid range");
  }
  var weights = range.getFontLine();
  var numbers = range.getValues();  
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
      if (weights[i][j] != "line-through" && typeof numbers[i][j] == "number") {
        x += numbers[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Thank you for all your attempts to help me in advance!

Comment: I put an example in the post update, but it only counts the number of cells, not a sum of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum cells if they are not bold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964794/sum-cells-if-they-are-not-bold)

Comment: There is no conceptual difference between these two questions you posted.

Comment: Yes, it is! I tried to change the source of "Sum cells if they are not bold" but it didn't work :-(. Please see the update № 2.

Comment: @soup, Maybe should I change something other in the source to make it working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the suggested answer with `getFontLines()` rather that `getFontLine()`:

```
function SumIfNotStrikethrough1(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i)[1].split("!");
  try {
    if (args.length == 1) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(args[0]);
    }
    else {
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName(args[0].replace(/'/g, ''));
      range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args.join("!") + " is not a valid range");
  }
  var lines = range.getFontLines();
  var numbers = range.getValues();  
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
      if (lines[i][j] != "line-through" && typeof numbers[i][j] == "number") {
        x += numbers[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Here is the formula to use it: `=SumIfNotStrikethrough1(A2:B3)`.

Now that seems to be working properly in its single use.