# Angular2 Typescript how to increment alphabet index

Tags: typescript, angular

I know how to do this in Php, as it is a simple, but i am struggling to get a version working.

```
for ($i = 'A'; $i < 'Z'; $i++) {                   
    $k = $i;
    $k++;
    echo "$i->$k, ";
}
```

Basically i want to pass a letter into a function and get the next letter in the alphabet. Is there any easy ways or directions that i could be pointed in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer into its character equivalent in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145030/convert-integer-into-its-character-equivalent-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
getNextLetter(char: String): String {
    code: Number = char.charCodeAt(0);
    code++;
    return String.fromCharCode(code);
}
```

Comment: ahh perfect just what i was trying to achieve! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code for you:

https://plnkr.co/edit/SP6LzMfLzeNniiteDmRQ?p=preview

```
var upper = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ];
var alphabet = {};

for(var j = 0; j < upper.length; j++)
  alphabet[upper[j]] = j;

console.log(alphabet);

function NextLetter(l)
{
  console.log('Current letter index:', alphabet[l]);
  console.log('Next letter:',upper[alphabet[l]+1] );
}

//Test 
NextLetter('C');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two nice JS functions that can help you out:

1. `charCodeAt` - extracts the letter Unicode.
2. `fromCharCode` - parse Unicode to a letter.

   ```
   var k, i = 'A'.charCodeAt();
   var loopEnd = 'Z'.charCodeAt();

   for (i; i < loopEnd; i++) {                   
       k = i;
       k++;
       console.log(String.fromCharCode(i) + " -> " + String.fromCharCode(k));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I modified the answer to this and it worked for me... from the fronted inside for loop just call getNextLetter(i);

typescript code:

```
 getNextLetter(num): String {
     var code: number = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charCodeAt(num);
     return String.fromCharCode(code); 
 }
```