# A loop to create the alphabet using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, numbers, letters

I've been working on a small project for myself, and it consists of creating the alphabet. I don't want to hard code each individual letter in markup, but rather use JavaScript to do it for me.

This is how far I've gotten.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 26; i++ ) {



var li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = "letter" + i + " ";
li.style.listStyle = "none";
li.style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("letter-main").appendChild(li);

}
```

That being said, I'm trying to avoid using jQuery for the time, as I am trying to gain a better understanding of JavaScript.

There's another post that goes over the same Idea, using character codes but with jQuery.

How would I go about this?

Comment: where do you get the letter from?

Comment: I haven't yet, but I know of only two methods. Either through a string of the alphabet, or through a loop of character codes

Comment: [Alphabet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alphabet): "a set of letters or other characters with which one or more languages are written especially if arranged in a customary order." JavaScript uses the Unicode character set. Neither have the concept of alphabet. Unicode has the concept of scripts but that generally means all the letter characters that were added to be used in a writing system for a language. (Devanagari for Hindi; Latin for English.) Both have the concept of collation or locale for ordering. (German, ä before z; Swedish, ä after z) So…, hard-coding is the way.

Comment: @TomBlodget actually I was provided the perfect answer I was looking for. Not necessarily exactly how It can be described but a simpler solution, as opposed to creating a full hard code set of letters. (see answer)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to convert a number to alpha

```js
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = "letter " + (i+10).toString(36) + " ";
  li.style.listStyle = "none";
  li.style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("letter-main").appendChild(li);

}
```

```html
<div id="letter-main"></div>
```

Answer (score 39):

Answer from [Convert integer into its character equivalent in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145054/5692251):

> Assuming you want lower case letters:
>       `var chr = String.fromCharCode(97 + n); // where n is 0, 1, 2 ...`
>   97 is the ASCII code for lower case 'a'. If you want uppercase letters, replace 97 with 65 (uppercase 'A'). Note that if n > 25, you will get out of the range of letters.

Comment: If anyone needs to create them into an array, use this one-liner `const alphabets = [...Array(26).keys()].map((n) => String.fromCharCode(97 + n));`

Change `97` to `65` for uppercase