# How do I convert a variable item to integer

Tags: node.js

```
var leter= "trypanosomiasis";

console.log(parseInt(leter));
```

I tried the code above and the one below

```
var leter= "trypanosomiasis";
console.log(Number(leter));
```

None of them seemed to work

Comment: That string isn't an number.

Comment: what number were you expecting to be returned from a string with no numbers?

Comment: there are not strict integers in JavaScript...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145030/convert-integer-into-its-character-equivalent-in-javascript

Comment: Oh thanks for the link, it is the ascii conversion I wanted. I want to add them together

Comment: Anyone know how I can convert a word to number equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need. Wrote a one-line function that sums all the character's ascii representation in a string. It splits the string into an array of characters and sum them up...

```
function sumASCII(inputString){
    return inputString.split('').reduce((sum, character)=>{ return sum + character.charCodeAt(0)}, 0);
}

console.log(sumASCII("abcd"));
```